# Add GPG signature using Windows Subsystem for Linux

Tags: gnupg, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Started by installing [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Then, installed **rng-tools** by executing this command:

```
sudo apt-get install rng-tools
```

and executing the following command

```
gpg --gen-key
```

generated an RSA key with size 3072 expiring in 2022-03-16.

Thing is, I wanted to specify a 2048 bits with no expiration date.

My previous experience using Ubuntu/Debian environment following the steps above always asked which kind of passphrase I wanted, the keysize, how long the key should be valid, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `gpg --gen-key --interactive` or `gpg --full-generate-key` for a more full feature set (selection of type of key, etc.).

If it didn't prompt you for details, then somehow your gen-key system is using defaults pulled from a file or a configuration set somewhere.  Usually, I always use `gpg --full-generate-key` to get all the prompts I expect to get (but I'm old-school that way).

(This said, something must be odd in your WSL environment - `gpg --gen-key` works as expected and prompts for data in my freshly configured WSL + 18.04 LTS environment)